# Set orientation to Portrait with certain popups in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, tablet, device-orientation

I have an application that I've written in Adobe Flex.

I have my main information view with two pop ups: A login popup followed by an enter details pop up which returns the required information.

These pop ups work as desired in portrait orientation and not as desired in landscape orientation. I would like to have the orientation locked to portrait mode while these two pop up windows are up and then unlocked after.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can add listeners for the change event and in certain cases (use a model to store if you're in those particular cases) use preventDefault to stop the event from doing it's normal thing.  More on orientation and controlling it here: 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/screen_orientation_apis.html